Computing character polynomial for irreducible representation
Given a partition $\lambda = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_r), a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \dots \geq a_r$ and $n$ such that $n - \sum a_i \geq a_1$, let $V(\lambda)_n$ be the irreducible representation of $S_n$ given by the partition $(n - \sum a_i, a_1, \dots, a_r)$. It is well known that the family $V(\lambda) = \{V(\lambda)_n\}$ of $S_n$ representations for all $n$ has character simultaneously given by the same character polynomial $\chi^\lambda$. What is an efficient way of computing this character polynomial with a computer? Alternatively, is there an implementation of this in sage?

I think I've found a good solution and I'll keep this here in case others find it useful.
In Macdonald's Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials in example 1.7.14, there is a formula for $\chi^\lambda$, also referenced here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.10633 as Theorem 2.1.
$$\chi^\lambda = \sum_{|\rho| \leq |\lambda|} F^\lambda_\rho \binom{a}{\rho} $$
$$F_\rho^\lambda = (-1)^{|\lambda| - |\rho|} \sum_\mu \chi^\mu_\rho$$
Where the $\mu$ are summed over all partitions satisfying $|\mu| = |\rho|$ and such that $\lambda$ can be obtained from adding $|\lambda| - |\mu|$ boxes to $|\mu|$ without ever adding two boxes to the same row.
Thus, the main computation is determining the values $\chi^\mu_{\rho}$. Since I am aiming to compute these character polynomials $\chi^{\lambda}$ for all $\lambda$ with $k$ boxes or less, this is well suited to using the recursive Murnaghan–Nakayama rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murnaghan%E2%80%93Nakayama_rule. Along with memoization where possible I achieved drastic speedups from my previous implementation.
